# jQuery Mobile bottom navigation bar

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there working jQuery Mobile sample code for iPhone/Mobile Safari bottom navigation bar?

I have tried to google and code myself but I never really got it working for iPhone/Mobile Safari. The other browsers seem to be fine e.g. Desktop Safari, Desktop Chrome, Android browser.

The code that I tried (and it works just not for Mobile Safari .. doh)

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" data-icon="custom">Entry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-icon="custom">Winner</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three" data-icon="custom">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following working example, using custom icons (using jQuery Mobile 1.2.0):

Create a css file `mycss.css` and include the following in it:

```
.ui-icon-custom {
    background: url("../img/run.png") no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
}
```

where `run.png` is the name of your custom icon.

Then, in your html file, include the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- LOAD YOUR CSS FILE WHILE PAYING ATTENTION TO ITS PATH! -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/mycss.css"/>

</head>    

<body>

    <div data-role="page">      

        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>This is my content</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#one" data-icon="custom">Entry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#two" data-icon="custom">Winner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#three" data-icon="custom">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->                             
        </div> 

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot (iPhone 5):**

[image: screenshot]

**PS:** Pay attention to the paths of your css / png files!

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This code is a workaround for the built in method in my answer. This may break with future updates/versions of jQuery Mobile as it is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="a.html">Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="b.html">Friends</a></li>
            <li><a href="c.html">Albums</a></li>
            <li><a href="d.html">Emails</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Comes straight from the [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html)

If it's not working for you, I would look at the markup of the rest of your page as something is probably not coded correctly. Also, make sure you're using the latest stable build of jQuery Mobile (1.2.0) and jQuery (1.8.2)

Here's a [basic example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQhGA/).

Comment: By using the answer you accepted you are working outside of the jQuery Mobile framework, and therefore your code may break with future updates/versions. I'd recommend using the code I provided which is directly taken from the jQuery Mobile framework.